# VBAでone drive内のフォルダへのアクセスについて教えてください

Tags: windows, vba

VBAでone drive内のフォルダへのアクセスについて教えてください

VBAでone drive同期をしているフォルダのパス名を取得すると https://xx.sharepoint.com/personal/yy_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/zz というパス名が

取得されます
（取得の仕方によって ローカルなパス名が取得されるときもあるのですが、、、）

このフォルダに対し、特定のサブフォルダがあるかどうかを調べたくて
dir("https://xx.sharepoint.com/personal/yy_onmicrosoft_com/Documents/zz /NEWFOLDERNAME", vbDirectory)
をすると 
実行時エラー'52' ファイル名または番号が不正です。
のエラーとなります

質問１
上記のようなone driveフォルダのパス名から、そのフォルダと同期しているローカルなフォルダのパス名を取得する方法はありますか？
（ローカルパスで dir をかけるとエラーにはならないと思いますので）

質問２
one drive上で フォルダの存在確認や、存在しないときに新規作成するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

当然ながら、いろいろ検索をしてみたのですが、該当する内容は見つかりませんでした

よろしくお願いします